# setting FTP proxy with snakemake FTP provider

Tags: snakemake

I'm trying to download files from a ftp server using snakemake "snakemake.remote.FTP" as follows:

```
from snakemake.remote.FTP import RemoteProvider as FTPRemoteProvider

FTP = FTPRemoteProvider()
chrList = [*range(1,23)]

...

# Download 1K genomes vcf files
rule download1kgenomes:
    input:  FTP.remote(expand("ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502/ALL.chr{chr}.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5b.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz",chr=chrList), keep_local=True, immediate_close=True),
            FTP.remote(expand("ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502/ALL.chr{chr}.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5b.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz.tbi",chr=chrList), keep_local=True, immediate_close=True),
            FTP.remote("ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502/20140625_related_individuals.txt", keep_local=True, immediate_close=True),
            FTP.remote("ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502/integrated_call_samples_v3.20130502.ALL.panel", keep_local=True, immediate_close=True),
    output: expand(config["refPanelDir"]+"/ALL.chr{chr}.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5b.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz",chr=chrList),
            expand(config["refPanelDir"]+"/ALL.chr{chr}.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5b.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz.tbi",chr=chrList),
            config["refPanelDir"]+"/20140625_related_individuals.txt",
            config["refPanelDir"]+"/integrated_call_samples_v3.20130502.ALL.panel"
    params: outdir = config["refPanelDir"]
    run:
            shell("mv {input} {params.outdir}")
```

This works perfectly well under a normal internet connection and I think it's a great snakemake feature. Unfortunately, my university is behind a proxy and when I try this at the office, I get error messages when failing to connect to the remote server:

```
File "/my/path/to/python3.9/site-packages/ftputil/error.py", line 199, in __exit__
    raise FTPOSError(*exc_value.args, original_error=exc_value) from exc_value
ftputil.error.FTPOSError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
Debugging info: ftputil 5.0.1, Python 3.9.5 (linux)
```

Does anybody know how to specify a ftp proxy setting to snakemake and if this is even possible?
Regards